# Unordered list bullet not remaining to the left of the list. Format of list is not working for all devices

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I would like to have the custom bullet in this unordered list remain to the left of each listed item no matter what the screen size is. It seems to be going on top of the list item from the phone view.

Also, the list alignment in the desktop view I put as displayed as an inline-block and I want the text-alignment to show up as justified as I put in the code. I must be missing something here because it doesn't look justified.

The alignment in the tablet view goes into two columns as I would like it to be that way but one of the list item "chits" near the end jets out to the right a bit even though it doesn't exceed the length of the first column. I only want the "and more" to jet out beneath the list (as I have set with a left margin).

```css
.listexamples {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.listexamples {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
 }

.listexamples::before {
    content: "•";
    color: #FFEC6C;
    vertical-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

/*experimental media tag*/
@media(max-width: 790px) {
  ul {
        display: 100% ;
        font-size:14px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding: none;
    column-count: 2;

    }
    
}

.more {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="center"><h2>Examples of what I can provide</h2>
<ul>
    <li class="listexamples">Branded polos</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Custom t-shirts</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Branded mugs</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Business cards</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Branded pens</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Newsletters</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Printed menus</li>
   <li class="listexamples">Printed fliers</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Chits</li>
<p class="more">and more!</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: why is there a p in the UL? That is invalid HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Added responsive support in the codepen version [here](https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/poyaxMV) ; the code below is *not* updated.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Here is a code that will work I think, I will explain it below.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;flex-direction:column;
}

.listexamples {
 }

.listexamples::before {
    content: "•";
    color: red;
    width: 1em;
    margin:0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="center">
    <h2>Examples of what I can provide</h2>
<ul>
    <li class="listexamples">Branded polos</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Custom t-shirts</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Branded mugs</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Business cards</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Branded pens</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Newsletters</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Printed menus</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Printed fliers</li>
    <li class="listexamples">Chits</li>
</ul>
  
<p class="more">and more!</p>
```

So I cleaned your code a bit, there was a few lines of code that had no effect so I removed them (i.e. the margin-right on the li items etc.)

So the main idea here is to add a flex display to the unordered list (ul) and a flex-direction column so that no matter the width of the screen it will be displayed vertically. I have also removed your experimental media tag as I dont think it is needed. Finally, I have added a double horizontal margin to your list items. Any questions?

Comment: What if I would like the list to be horizontal on the desktop view and then when it goes to the tablet view, 2 columns, and then one column for the phone view? 

There is a collage image which spans across the page underneath the list (showing some items mentioned) and I would like it to be higher up with the list for the desktop view so that people don't have to scroll to see it. It seems that the template I'm working within in wordpress automatically adds extra space between the list items.

Thanks.

Comment: I did something that renders what you described, and it only adds 4 lines of code. See here: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/poyaxMV   // try resizing slowly the window and you will see it happening.

Comment: Glad I could help!